# OutOfMemory in simple Zig use case

Tags: memory, zig

I'm learning Zig and i'm confused with an `OutOfMemoryError`.

In theory, the file that i'm trying to read has 9 bytes of size. The `max_bytes`parameter of `readToEndAlloc`is setted to 9 but the problem i think is the `FixedBufferAllocator`.

If i don't set the `fixed_alloc_buf` to `[2048]u8` or more then i have the out of memory error. If i try to run this code with `[16]u8` then doesn't work:

```
const std = @import("std");

pub fn main() !void {
    const file = try std.fs.cwd().openFile("./file.txt", .{}); // file of 9 bytes
    defer file.close();

    var fixed_alloc_buf: [16]u8 = undefined; // boom if not [~2048]u8
    var fixed_alloc = std.heap.FixedBufferAllocator.init(&fixed_alloc_buf);

    var arena = std.heap.ArenaAllocator.init(fixed_alloc.allocator());
    defer arena.deinit();

    const allocator = arena.allocator();
    const buffer = try file.readToEndAlloc(allocator, 9);
    defer allocator.free(buffer);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two things:

- [`ArenaAllocator`](https://ziglang.org/documentation/0.11.0/std/#A;std:heap.ArenaAllocator) needs [some memory](https://github.com/ziglang/zig/blob/0.11.x/lib/std/heap/arena_allocator.zig#L163) for its own internal state.
- And it also allocates more than you request. As it tries to keep the memory "chunked".

In this case it tries to get 63 bytes from the parent allocator:

```
const std = @import("std");

pub fn main() !void {
    var gpa = std.heap.GeneralPurposeAllocator(.{ .verbose_log = true }){};
    defer std.debug.assert(gpa.deinit() == .ok);
    const allocator = gpa.allocator();

    var arena = std.heap.ArenaAllocator.init(allocator);
    defer arena.deinit();

    _ = try arena.allocator().alloc(u8, 9);
}
```

This prints:

```
$ zig build run
info(gpa): small alloc 63 bytes at u8@1e6234e0000
info(gpa): small free 63 bytes at u8@1e6234e0000
```